# How to check the communication options of an entire web server using the HTTP OPTIONS method?

Tags: http, python-requests, postman

According to [the documentation of the HTTP OPTIONS method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS), one can check the communication options of an entire web server, assuming the server supports such a check. My understanding is that one needs to make an HTTP request to the server to be checked with the first line of the request being `OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1`. How can one make such a request with a common HTTP client? I wasn't able do it with the Postman client or the Requests HTTP client library for Python. Specifically, specifying the asterisk `*` along with the server's location, `http://<host>/*`, for example, didn't work.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what didn't work? Have you tried the ```requests.options()``` method?

Comment: Yes, I have tried `requests.option`. In particular, I have tried `requests.options("http://127.0.0.1:5000/*")` against a Flask app in the local host. That didn't work because the `path_url` for the request was set to `/*`.